# SSH into Vagrant box as another user using key?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualenv, ansible

I like using the "vagrant" user to provision my Vagrant VM using Ansible.  But once I get the box set up, I'd like to be able to log in to it using either the vagrant account or my personal account "smith."  However, when I log in as smith, I'd like to not be prompted for my password.  Is there a way to set this up?  I've created the smith account on the Vagrant box and I've copied my public and private SSH keys from my .ssh directory on the OS X management host to user smith's .ssh directory on the VM.  Right now I can log in by doing "ssh smith@192.168.2.100" but I get prompted for my password.  Is there any way to configure both machines so that I can log in using my SSH keys?

Thanks.

```
# Vagrantfile
DEV_GID = 1001
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.100"
  config.vm.synced_folder "website/", "/srv/http/example.com",
      owner: "root",
      group: DEV_GID,
      mount_options: ["dmode=775"]
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying all the files in the .ssh directory, you should create the file

```
 /home/smith/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(or wherever your home folder in the vagrant box is) in your vagrand box and copy-paste your id_rsa.pub inside this file. By copying-paste I mean open id_rsa.pub with an editor, copy all of it, and paste it in .ssh/authorized_keys file. You should also change the directory permissions to 0600.

Your private id_rsa file is not needed in the vagrant box, it is only needed in the host you use to ssh into that vagrant box.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks so much!